# How can I create a clickable "outline" of our JavaScript and PHP code in PhpStorm (or free 3rd party tool)

Tags: javascript, php, phpstorm

In some other programming environments, there are ways to create an outline (or perhaps even just bookmarks to the code).

I suppose one way to do this is just an HTML file with links to the sections of code. However, I'd like to avoid having to put bookmarks in a .js or .html file.

**Examples:**

1. HTML "outline file" with links to particular bit of code. Ideally linking based on the inherent semantics in .js an php. (so perhaps linking to a function definition. Goal of this would be just to "bookmark" the most important parts of the program for easier navigation. I.e., manually find an link to the Code for: (I'll use a game metaphor)

   1. Create New user
   2. Start game
   3. Game Finished (or "Score Screen")
   4. Save Game
   5. Load Saved Game
2. Creat a call tree, so you can visually see what code calls which code.

Comment: Could you please provide some examples (screenshots etc) of the required functionality?

Comment: @LazyOne hows' that?

Comment: xdebug + kcachegrind or wincachegrind .. although I suppose its not exactly what you want. As it will not include js.

Comment: Isn't this the functionality you want https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/viewing-structure-of-a-source-file.html ? The call tree, that you mention is probably only achievable through runtime debugging, therefore xdebug would be necessary. You can connect your IDE to xdebug then (we're talking PHP here, JS is a whole other story, but the developer tools should suffice. Alternatively there are also plugins to connect your browser to your IDE, https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/using-jetbrains-chrome-extension.html).

Comment: I also want to be able to create my own bookmarks (create my own outline with links to the important part of the code).  The logical structure of the program my not be reflected in the call tree (or at least it may not be obvious where the "critical" events are.

Comment: @user5542121   is wincachegrind just the windows  'alternative' of kcache*  ? I could not tesll if Win* has the visual call tree display. That's really nice.

Comment: @ClayNichols yes wincachegrind is the windows 'alternative'. Also PHPStorm has also an anzalyzer for those *.cachegrind files. See https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/analyzing-xdebug-profiling-data.html


And lastly there are a few other tools which can work with cachegrind files, like qcachegrind, or completely different tools like https://github.com/chrisakers/Xdebug-Trace-Visualizer .

Addendum, you might also want to look in to phpdocumentor or doxygen. As those actually do create documentation and outline of classes..